# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION while adding google play services

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am developing an android app where I am integrating Google Plus Login. For this, I've added google play services library to my project. When I run my app, it gives me following error :

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

This is my build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.genes_x.googleplus"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
        compile files('E:/google plus/GooglePlus/libs/google-play-services.jar')
    }
```

I've been gone through many questions on stackoverflow but didn't get solution. Anything wrong in my build.gradle file..??

Comment: Not sure why you are giving absolute path of the jar file. Definitely problem in dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty obvious. You are compiling google play services twice. Should be:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
    //compile files('E:/google plus/GooglePlus/libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```